# Setting layout_marginBottom for TableLayout inside LinearLayout has no effect

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a vertical LinearLayout *(green rectangle)*, and I'm trying to programatically inflate and insert multiple TableLayouts *(red rectangle)* to this LinearLayout. Each tablelayout contains 4 cells in a 2x2 arrangement.

[image]

It works except that any layout_marginBottom I set for the TableLayout has no effect, the red rectangles are always tightly packed inside the LinearLayout. I would like to create some vertical spacing in between each table.

Please suggest what is wrong with my XML:

LinearLayout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/levellist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

TableLayout (inserted dynamically). Note the layout_marginBottom that has no effect :

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/levelview0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            layout="@layout/levelmenu_level" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/levelview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            layout="@layout/levelmenu_level" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/levelview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            layout="@layout/levelmenu_level" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/levelview3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            layout="@layout/levelmenu_level" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of Views in this TableLayout that are the same. I would suggest trying to use a GridLayout. It should help with so memory management and recycling. But to answer your question, it looks like your are setting the margin for the entire table, not each row. Have you tried putting your layout_margin inside of your row tag? You can also try setting the Padding instead? That way you put the spacing inside of the rows. However, I believe you should get the same effect either way. Margin is outside of the view, padding is inside.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:paddingBottom

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="???dip">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/levelview0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            layout="@layout/levelmenu_level" />
```

Comment: Yes, I would like to set the margin between each table, not between each row. I would like to use margin and not padding, because I plan to use a background image for the table, and I would like blank space between where one background starts and another begins. I'm just curious why I'm not able to set a margin at the bottom of a table.

Comment: You want padding in between each of your "levels." And you have one big tablelayout and are including each level in the rows of your table. So move your spacing into the tags for those rows.

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate your attempt to help, but I think you misunderstood me. No, I don't have one big tablelayout. I have one big linearlayout. The linearlayout holds multiple tables (each red rectangle in the image is a table). Each table holds 4 cells. I want to create a spacing in between each table (not each row). It could be changed around to be one big table, but that's not the particular question I'm asking.